# Multiple accounts with RefineryCMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I am thinking to use RefineryCMS for multiple accounts, thus each use can create his own pages, his own images .. etc

What I need to know please is:

1. How would I mount RefineryCMS for each user ( via his id for example ) ?? I can work without this, but its really better to organize routes.
2. Adding user_id to Refinery page model, will I be able to show only pages for some user id in the admin page? is that it?
3. Configure Dragonfly to use different buckets on amazon s3 ?

Has any one tried this before? What else would I consider then?
Thanks

Comment: have you found a solution sir?